# Railsでグループ単位で値を集計（SUM)し、各グループごとの集計結果を表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, chart.js

**実現したいこと**

Railsでグループ単位で値を集計（SUM)し、各グループごとの集計結果をControllerで変数として定義したい

※その後、定義した変数について、gem gonを活用してJavaScriptに定義した値を加える予定です。

**イメージ**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 環境・条件

・Ruby：2.6.5
・Rails:5.2.4.3
・DB：PostgreSQL
・DB設計 ※詳細は下記コード
親：Recordテーブル（属性：id,その他）
子：Practiceテーブル（属性：id,practice_item, practice_time）
※practice_itemで格納される値は、string型かつ決まった文字列

#### 試したこと

**構想**
★ゴール：chart.jsにRuby変数を組み込んで変数の値をaggrigate_results.html.slimに表示させること

そのために必要となる要素
★全てのRecordテーブルのレコードから、practice_itemごとに格納されている全てのpractice_timeの値を合計したものをオブジェクトとすること

★そのために必要な実装
1.全てのrecordを取り出す
2.全てのrecordが取り出せたら、PracticeテーブルのPractice_itemを分類して棲み分けさせる
3.棲み分けしたpractice_itemの全てのpractice_timeの値をsumメソッドなどで合計値を計算し、それをまた1つのオブジェクトとする
4.practice_itemごとの合計値が含まれる集合を、ハッシュか配列で定義する
5.定義したハッシュか配列をViewで表示できるようJSを修正する

★1.2.3を実施（＝Practiceテーブルにある、practice_item,practice_timeを両方検索して取り出す。その後practice_timeをSUM関数で集計）

```
  def aggregate_result

  @record = current_user.records.includes(:practices).select("practice_item", "practice_time").group("practice_item").sum(:practice_time)
  logger.info "test #{@record}"
  gon.data = @record
  end
```

それでログを確認したところ、下記の通りとなったのですが、その後4.5.をどのようにすれば良いのか？ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

※現時点の内容を画面確認しましたが、エラーにはなっていないものの、表示はされていないです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もしくは、やり方が違うのでは？と言うものがあれば、遠慮なく仰って頂ければ幸いです。

```
tarted POST "/__better_errors/1d27c32fbb9084fd/variables" for ::1 at 2020-06-20 23:40:45 +0900
Started GET "/records/3/aggregate_result" for ::1 at 2020-06-20 23:40:46 +0900
Processing by RecordsController#aggregate_result as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.6ms)  SELECT SUM(practice_time) AS sum_practice_time, practice_item AS practice_item FROM "records" LEFT OUTER JOIN "practices" ON "practices"."record_id" = "records"."id" WHERE "records"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY practice_item  [["user_id", "3"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/records_controller.rb:57
test {"多球練習"=>222, "サーブ練習"=>170, "フットワーク"=>30, "オール"=>22, "台上処理"=>120}
  Rendering records/aggregate_result.html.slim within layouts/application
  Rendered records/_flash_messages.html.slim (2.0ms)
  Rendered records/aggregate_result.html.slim within layouts/application (6.1ms)
  Rendered records/_header.html.slim (3.1ms)
  Rendered records/_footer.html.slim (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 29.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

**コード**

Controller

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @q = current_user.records.ransack(params[:q])
    @search_records = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:practices).page(params[:page]).per(8)
  end

  def show
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @record = Record.new
    output = @record.outputs.build
    practice = @record.practices.build
    task = @record.tasks.build
  end

  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)
    logger.info "###### #{@record.inspect}"
    if @record.save
      flash[:success] = "練習内容の登録が完了しました。"
      redirect_to records_url
    else
      flash[:alert] = "登録に失敗しました。"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @record = Record.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @record = Record.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @record.update(record_params)
        flash[:success] = "練習内容の更新が完了しました。"
        redirect_to records_url
      else
        flash[:alert] = "更新に失敗しました。"
        render :edit
      end
  end

  def destroy
    record = Record.find_by(id:params[:id])
    record.destroy

    redirect_to root_path, notice: "練習記録を削除しました。"
  end

  def aggregate_result
  @record = current_user.records.includes(:practices).select("practice_item", "practice_time").group("practice_item").sum(:practice_time)
  logger.info "test #{@record}"
  gon.data = @record
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = current_user || User.new
  end

  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:record_id, :training_date, :learning_point, outputs_attributes:[:output_name, :id, :_destroy], practices_attributes:[:practice_item, :practice_time, :id, :_destroy], tasks_attributes:[:task_name, :id, :_destroy]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

schema.rb（一部）

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_05_25_064157) do

  create_table "practices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "practice_item"
    t.integer "practice_time"
    t.bigint "record_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["record_id"], name: "index_practices_on_record_id"
  end

  create_table "records", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "user_id"
    t.text "learning_point"
    t.date "training_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

aggregate_result.html.slim

```
= render 'records/flash_messages'
h1 レポート
canvas#myPieChart
script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"
javascript:
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
  var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ["サーブ練習", "フットワーク", "3球目攻撃", "台上処理","多球練習","オール"],
      datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(242,68,172,0.2)'
          ],
          data: gon.data
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: '練習内容の内訳'
      }
    }
  });

= link_to '一覧に戻る', root_path, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 0):

chart.jsで表示するデータは配列で渡すようです。
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure

`aggregate_result.html.slim`でデータを渡している`gon.data`を配列に変えればグラフが表示されそうです。
また、SlimでインラインJavascriptを使うのであれば、Gon経由で渡さずに変数展開しちゃえばいいかなと思います。

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: #{@record.keys},
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(242,68,172,0.2)",
        ],
        data: #{@record.values},
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "練習内容の内訳",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: user40752さん、ご返信ありがとうございます。 そうですね、配列を渡せば、Char .jsに表示できることは確認できました。 ただ、上記と同じように、gonを消去してslimを提示の通りに実装してみましたが、エラーは出ないものの、ちゃんと円グラフに反映されませんでした。。。